# ts file change not detected by NG Live Development server

Tags: angular

Just playing with Angular CLI.

Here is what I did:

1. npm install -g angular-cli
2. ng new PROJECT_NAME
3. cd PROJECT_NAME
4. ng serve
5. hit the page at: http://localhost:4200/ in browser
6. change app.component.ts file, no change in browser
7. change app.component.html file, new change is automatically reflected in browser

What is that my change in ts file not detected?

Comment: What does your browser console say? @Tao Lu

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with webpack 1.2.5. Rolling back one version worked for me.

> Just run:
>
> ```
> npm install --save @ngtools/webpack@1.2.4
> ```

You can read more about this issue here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4338

Answer (score 0):

You should install angular cli using:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

and not:

`npm install -g angular-cli`

Make sure you're using the [latest version](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases) and if not, [update your Angular CLI to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version).

If you have still change detection issue, using the following solved the issue for me (on Ubuntu):

`echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`