# NG Live Development Server requires restart to see changes

Tags: angular

I'm going through the Tour of Heroes tutorial on angular.io, and it appears that I need to restart the server in order to actually see my changes.

I created my project with `@angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.32.3`

My project's dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
```

`npm list | grep webpack` gives me:

```
│ ├─┬ @ngtools/webpack@1.2.10
│ ├─┬ extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.0.0
│ │ └── webpack-sources@0.1.4
│ ├─┬ html-webpack-plugin@2.28.0
│ ├─┬ karma-webpack@2.0.2
│ │ └── webpack-dev-middleware@1.10.1
│ ├─┬ webpack@2.2.1
│ ├─┬ webpack-dev-server@2.3.0
│ └── webpack-merge@2.6.1
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011126/ts-file-change-not-detected-by-ng-live-development-server) which suggests installing `@ngtools/webpack@1.2.4`, and I tried that, but it only resulted in more errors.

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version [1.0.0-rc.0](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of the angular cli. The `32` version had several bugs. Make sure to follow their update and migration guide though, stated in their [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and [readme.md](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/README.md)

Another thing that mysteriously worked for me, is to turn off safe write option inside intellij. But that of course only works if you use a jetbrains IDE :)

Comment: Hrm, I updated to `@angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.0` and I have the same issue. I completely regenerated my project too. `node --version` says `v7.6.0`.

Comment: So you removed your locale node_modules folder? Removed the global angular cli and reinstalled everything again?

Comment: I didn't re-install `@angular/cli`, but I made sure it was up to date (`1.0.0-rc.0`), and then I obliterated my `tour-of-heroes` folder and re-created it with `ng new tour-of-heroes`. I've been working through the tutorial and this issue happens sporadically. Sometimes it updates, sometimes it doesn't, and when it doesn't, there isn't always indication as to why... I'll even open up the JavaScript console, and I won't see any indication of a problem whatsoever, even though it's very plain that my code has changed, and those changes are not appearing. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: One particular issue I'm seeing is... after adding `styles: \`...\`` to my @Component decorator, I'm not seeing them applied, no matter how many times I refresh, re-start the transpiler, etc.

Comment: the right course of action is still to remove the global `@angular-cli`, run a `npm cache clean` and install it again. If that doesn't work, try the suggestion i put in my answer about intellij