# How to upgrade Angular CLI to the latest version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using `ng --version` I got:

> @angular/cli: 1.0.0

which is not the latest release available.

Since I have Angular CLI globally installed on my system, in order to upgrade it I tried:

`npm update angular-cli -g`

But it does not work, because it stays to 1.0.0 version.

Answer (score 1461, accepted):

After reading some issues reported on the GitHub repository, I found the solution.

In order to update the angular-cli package installed globally in your system, you need to run:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Depending on your system, you may need to prefix the above commands with `sudo`.

Also, most likely you want to also update your local project version, because inside your project directory it will be selected with higher priority than the global one:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

thanks *grizzm0* for pointing this out on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4391#issuecomment-277199786).

After updating your CLI, you probably want to [update your Angular version](https://update.angular.io/) too.

**Note**: if you are updating to Angular CLI 6+ from an older version, you might need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926816/ng-build-prod-does-not-minify-uglify-remove-comments-since-angular-cli-6/51926817).

**Edit**: In addition, if you were still on a 1.x version of the cli, you need to convert your `angular-cli.json` to `angular.json`, which you can do with the following command (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232874/angular-6-migration-angular-cli-json-to-angular-json) for more details):

```
ng update @angular/cli --from=1.7.4 --migrate-only
```

Comment: Pedantic alert: You can find more details about changes between versions in the Releases tab on GitHub. Link: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases

Comment: If you are experiencing problems using these commands especially on windows machines. Try adding the   --on-optional  flag on both the npm install and uninstall commands.

Comment: Update 2017 (npm@5) : if you really need to clean your cache : "npm cache clean --force"

Comment: why uninstall angular-cli and not whole @angular/cli?

Comment: This is taken from the official notes. They uninstall angular-cli because it was the name of the package before the version 1.5 (I think), so it's recommended to remove it before installing the package under the new name (@angular/cli).

Comment: Running the command npm cache clean throws error 'As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to makesure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.' "if you want to force, you can add --force

Comment: @PushkalBoganatham as @neyt stated, you need to use the `--force` flag

Comment: Pls. replace 'npm cache clean' with 'npm cache verify' for latest versions of npm.

Comment: Post @angular/cli@6.0.0 you only need one single command i.e

    **ng update @angular/cli**

Comment: # updating using npm
$ npm i -g @angular/cli
$ npm i @angular/cli

# using Yarn
$ yarn global add @angular/cli
$ yarn add @angular/cli

Comment: This is still working for Angular CLI: 6.1.2 update to Angular CLI: 6.1.3 using Node: 8.11.3

Comment: use --force if terminal not allow to do this like npm cache clean --force

Comment: Strange, updating from A6 to A7, when installing the @latest version globally, I end up with the same version (6.2.4). On a Mac, NPM 8.9.4. Did a `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` which removed it globally. But after installing again, I got the same version of 6.

Comment: @Mattijs, I have same problem.  But, I am on Windows and I have npm version 6.4.1 .   I even used npm cache verify --force  and manually deleted the npm/node_modules/@angular folder.

Comment: @rickz I ended up installing version`@angular/cli@7.0.4` which worked

Comment: use @next for beta version `npm install -g @angular/cli@next`,
@latest for stable version  `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`, and 
@{{version_code}} for exact version like `npm install -g @angular/cli@7.0.0`

Comment: Just to bring this up to date, here it is from the horse's mouth (which means 'official source'): https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: In my case `ng v` command just wasn't reflecting the new version right after `npm i`. Closing the terminal, opening it again and running `ng v` again showed the latest version

Comment: If you need to upgrade to last version on windows you can:

- Open PowerShell Command Prompt as Admin
- Set PowerShell Execution Policy : Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
- Install npm Upgrader Tool : npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
- Upgrade npm Version: npm-windows-upgrade

For more information you can check https://linuxhint.com/how-to-update-npm-version-in-windows/

Comment: I had to delete this folder first: `C:\Users\My_Name\AppData\Roaming\npm` then re-install the CLI: `npm i -g @angular/cli`.

Comment: Best solution that always works for me in mac is to ```which ng``` then ```rm -rf {the output path}``` then what you did in the answer

Answer (score 266):

### First time users:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

### Update/upgrade:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

### Check:

```
ng --version
```

or Angular 14.X +

```
ng version
```

See [documentation](https://cli.angular.io/).

Comment: If you don't see the new version after Update/upgrade try closing and reopening the terminal and run `ng --version` again

Comment: Thanks. is `@latest` still needed to upgrade in 2021? What happens if I already have an older version of Angular CLI installed globally and don't include the `@latest` tag?

Comment: Yes do that and also in 2021 or yet 2022 you can Run "npx @angular/cli@13 update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13" which should bring you to version 13 of Angular since Angular now uses TypeScript 4.4 and is version 13. https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=12.0-13.0

Answer (score 161):

**ng6+ -> 7.0**

Update RxJS (depends on RxJS 6.3)

```
npm install -g rxjs-tslint
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
```

Remove `rxjs-compat`

Then update the core packages and Cli:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

(Optional: update Node.js to version 10 which is supported in NG7)

**ng6+ (Cli 6.0+)**: features simplified commands

First, update your Cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli
```

Then, update your core packages

```
ng update @angular/core
```

If you use RxJS, run

```
ng update rxjs
```

It will update RxJS to version 6 and install the `rxjs-compat` package under the hood.

If you run into build errors, try a manual install of:

```
npm i rxjs-compat
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Lastly, check your version

```
ng v
```

Note on production build:

ng6 no longer uses `intl` in `polyfills.ts`

```
//remove them to avoid errors
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

**ng5+ (Cli 1.5+)**

```
npm install @angular/{animations,common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router}@next typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'
npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save-exact
```

Note:

1. The supported Typescript version for Cli 1.6 as of writing is up to 2.5.3.
2. Using @next updates the package to beta, if available. Use @latest to get the latest non-beta version.

After updating both the global and local package, clear the cache to avoid errors:

```
npm cache verify (recommended)
npm cache clean (for older npm versions)
```

Here are the official references:

1. Updating the [Cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#user-content-updating-angular-cli)
2. Updating the core packages [core package](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/).

Comment: `npm cache clean --force`  Really helped me

Comment: can you please confirm what you said about RxJS 6 being deprecated. Everywhere I look it appears that v6 is the latest stable release https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: @JoeyGough nice catch! Ng7 depends on rxjs 6.3. Thanks for your comment. ref: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-700-2018-10-18

Answer (score 52):

The powerful command installs and replaces the last package.

I had a similar problem. I fixed it.

```
 npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

[image]

Comment: this will work for a local Angular CLI, check my answer to uprade the global one

Comment: upgraded my global cli

Answer (score 50):

The following approach worked for me:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

then

```
npm cache verify
```

then

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I work on Windows 10, sometimes I had to use: `npm cache clean --force` as well. You don't need to do if you don't have any problem during the installation.

Comment: You don't need to specify `@latest`, as latest is the default.

Comment: If this solution does not work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58678941/8718377

Answer (score 41):

This command works fine:

```
npm upgrade -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: This seems to upgrade the CLI to the latest minor version.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to [@ShinDarth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43931987/3345644).

I did what he said but my package did not updated the angular version, and I know that this post is about `angular-cli`, but i think that this can help too.

- so after doing what @ShinDarth said above, to fix my angular version I had to create a new project with `-ng new projectname` that generated a package.
- copy the new package, then paste the new package on all projects packages needing update (remember to add the dependencies you had and change the name on first line) or you can just change the versions manualy without copy and paste.
- then run `-npm install`.

Now my `ng serve` is working again, maybe there is a better way to do all that, if someone know, please share, because this is a pain to do with all projects that need update.

Comment: looks like more an addition to my answer than an answer, so maybe you can move it as a comment below my answer ?

Comment: sry, you are right but i need 50 of reputation to make a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, I have installed angular-cli locally using npm install --save-dev angular-cli.
So, when I use command `npm install -g @angular/cli`, it generates error saying

> Your global Angular CLI version (1.7.3) is greater than your local version (1.4.9)

Please note that angular-cli, @angular/cli and @angular/cli@latest are two different cli's.
What solves this is uninstall all cli and then install latest angular cli using

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 13):

To update **Angular CLI** to a new version, you must update both the global package and your project's local package.

**Global package:**

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
# if npm version is > 5 then use `npm cache verify` to avoid errors (or to avoid using --force)
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

**Local project package:**

```
rm -rf node_modules dist # use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist in Windows Command Prompt; use rm -r -fo node_modules,dist in Windows PowerShell
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

Source: [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)