# Error: npm ERR! write after end

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm

I am having issues installing  **Cordova** and **Ionic**.
At first I couldn't because of what seems to be a corrupted installation, that led me to uninstall NodeJS - Cordova - Ionic. 

Now, I've reinstalled NodeJS, without issues but when it comes to the famous line : 
`npm install -g cordova ionic`, I've got this error : 
 
`npm ERR! write after end`
then everytime I try to install cordova ionic, I've got the same error for a different package ... 
 Here are errors I get :

```
C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g cordova ionic
npm ERR! write after end    
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     d:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-07T09_31_22_439Z-debug.log    
C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g cordova ionic
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for ansi-styles@^3.2.1
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'chalk'
npm ERR! notarget    
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     d:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-07T09_40_04_399Z-debug.log    
C:\Windows\System32>
C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g cordova ionic
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for supports-color@^5.3.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'chalk'
npm ERR! notarget    
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     d:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-07T09_44_05_319Z-debug.log
```

If any of you can help me, it would be very appreciate ;-) Have a nice day...

EDIT 1 : after installing some packages and trying again, I've got this now :

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\path-is-absolute-86a430cb\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\parseurl-f42ab09d\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\path-is-absolute-86a430cb\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\opn-07c4c2dd\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\os-tmpdir-c1eaefc0\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\parse-glob-106d32b7\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\parseurl-f42ab09d\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\path-is-absolute-86a430cb\license'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\opn-07c4c2dd\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\os-tmpdir-c1eaefc0\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\parse-glob-106d32b7\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\parseurl-f42ab09d\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\superagent-4d7c9590\lib\agent-base.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\path-is-absolute-86a430cb\readme.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\os-tmpdir-c1eaefc0\license'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\opn-07c4c2dd\license'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\parse-glob-106d32b7\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\parseurl-f42ab09d\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\superagent-4d7c9590\lib\client.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\opn-07c4c2dd\readme.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\os-tmpdir-c1eaefc0\readme.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\parse-glob-106d32b7\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\parseurl-f42ab09d\HISTORY.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\opn-07c4c2dd\xdg-open'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\inquirer-b71d51ab\lib\utils\events.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\inquirer-b71d51ab\lib\utils\paginator.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\inquirer-b71d51ab\lib\utils\readline.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\inquirer-b71d51ab\lib\utils\screen-manager.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\readdirp-34d428ea\test\bed\root_dir2\root_dir2_file1.ext1'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\inquirer-b71d51ab\lib\utils\utils.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\readdirp-34d428ea\test\bed\root_dir2\root_dir2_file2.ext2'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\cordova-lib-a64e9936\src\cordova\metadata'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\qs-095a6ca4\lib\formats.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\qs-095a6ca4\lib\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\qs-095a6ca4\lib\parse.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\qs-095a6ca4\lib\stringify.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\qs-095a6ca4\lib\utils.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\cordova-app-hello-world-60bb7e30\template_src\res\icon\blackberry10'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\tiny-lr-cf15ff1c\src\client.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\tiny-lr-cf15ff1c\src\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\Profiles\cjolliet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\tiny-lr-cf15ff1c\src\server.js'
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting readable-stream@^2.0.5:
npm ERR! sha512-vuYxeWYM+fde14+rajzqgeohAI7YoJcHE7kXDAc4Nk0EbuKnJfqtY9YtRkLo/tqkuF7MsBQRhPnPeyjYITp3ZQ== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-vuYxeWYM+fde14+rajzqgeohAI7YoJcHE7kXDAc4Nk0EbuKnJfqtY9YtRkLo/tqkuF7MsBQRhPnPeyjYITp3ZQ== but got sha512-tK0yDhrkygt/knjowCUiWP9YdV7c5R+8cR0r/kt9ZhBU906Fs6RpQJCEilamRJj1Nx2rWI6LkW9gKqjTkshhEw==. (25689 bytes)
```

Comment: What is your node & npm version?

Comment: Node : v8.10.0
Npm : 5.7.1

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Try installing latest npm version this happens a lot with ionic.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm cache verify
npm i
```

If this doesn't work I advise you to switch to yarn. It's faster & easier to use. This is the [link](https://yarnpkg.com/docs/install/) to download YARN.
After installing just run this command  `yarn global add cordova ionic`

Ionic CLI uses npm by default. So go to your project & run `$ yarn install`.

If you want Ionic to use yarn by default run this: `$ ionic config set -g yarn true`

Comment: Still got issues after downgrading NPM.
Tried to use Yarn : no problem to install Ionic but when I started a project, errors with package.json files not found in ionic-angular and @ionic\app-scripts.

Comment: Yes this is normal behavior because ionic CLI uses npm by default. So go to your project & run yarn install  .If you want ionic to use yarn by default run this: ionic config set -g yarn true

Comment: To me "npm cache verify" and then "npm install" solved the issue

Comment: Worked on windows OS while it gives error on creating react project. Thank you.

Answer (score 31):

In my case, I didn't downgrade my npm because it will cause chaos in other dependencies. Instead, I tried running

```
npm cache verify
```

Error gone...

Answer (score 15):

Let, update the latest version of npm for running this command,

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Then run this command,

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Comment: No errors while the update, but still can't install Ionic with sames issues, but for ansi-styles@^3.2.1

Comment: I could install ansi-styles but at the next try to install, I got a lot of  warnings about missings files in node_modules\.staging and a ERR! code EINTEGRITY for a failed verification while readable-stream was extracting. I can post the full output if it can help in an answer.

Comment: this case uninstall ionic for this command==> npm uninstall -g cordova ionic 

Then close Node.js CMD and Now install ionic cordova==> npm install -g cordova ionic

Comment: The installation of ionic seems to work but when I tried to create the project, got ERR: code ETARGET, no matching version found for ansi-styles

Comment: Regarding ERR:code ETARGET error please create a new question.

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/43931987/2919078 and I hope this will fine

Answer (score 5):

It happened to me when I tried to install a ionic3 project with npm@5.8, well I solved this issue just add some params, use the following:

```
npm i --unsafe-perm
```

and it works.

Answer (score 5):

This still happens randomly on some npm versions. Issue got resolved on downgrading to npm version 5.6.0 using command

```
npm install -g npm@5.6.0
```

Hope that will help someone.

Answer (score 5):

## Update July 28, 2018

This problem is related to npm version **5.7.1**

Upgrading to node version **8.11.3** with npm version **5.8.0** solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

Just run 
`npm cache verify`

This will clean it all.

Answer (score 4):

i faced the same issue. For my case, i update npm to latest 6.1.0  by running "npm install -g npm@latest". Then run "npm cache verify

Answer (score 2):

Usually this error is **due to your Antivirus** blocking access to changing the files, to solve this:

1- You can try to turn your Antivirus off (temporarily) & try the installation again

2- If that alone doesn't work, try using the --force option while installing

I had this issue with some packages & it was solved by using one of the 2 steps above.

For example:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic --force
```

Answer (score -1):

None of the previous answers could help me.

Fortunately, after a lot of 'try and error', I found the following simple solution:

- delete (or move) the file '**package-lock.json**' and `npm install` works
  flawlessly.

Tip: if you have your project in a git repository:

- add the file '**package-lock.json**' in '.gitignore'