# What is the reason npm ERR! write after end, when I create an Angular 4 app?

Tags: angular

I am getting error when i create a Angular 4 app in CLI mode.

### I am getting this error

```
anjan@anjan-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~/Desktop/angular$ ng new a4app
npm ERR! write after end  
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/anjan/.npm/_logs/2018-04-13T04_48_09_522Z-debug.log
```

Please give me a proper suggestion so that i can solve this problem.

### My Angular configuration

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.0.0-rc.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.5.6
@angular-devkit/core         0.5.6
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.5.6
@ngtools/json-schema         1.1.0
@schematics/angular          0.5.6
@schematics/update           0.5.6
rxjs                         6.0.0-turbo-rc.4
typescript                   2.7.2
```

Comment: Please take a look on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49149508/2919078

Comment: please add more error trace

Comment: I already see this link, But at this moment i can't change the npm version for a Blockchain project.

Comment: @Sravan I put all of my error in this post, you want to see 2018-04-13T04_48_09_522Z-debug.log?

Comment: Any more error lines in terminal?

Comment: No just give me this error: 
1. npm ERR! write after end 
2. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
3. npm ERR!     /home/anjan/.npm/_logs/2018-04-13T04_48_09_522Z-debug.log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
npm install -g npm@5.6.0
```

After running this command my problem is solved.

Comment: Updating npm helped me too. I would suggest running `npm i -g npm` to update npm to latest version instead of keeping the 5.6.0 one.

Answer (score 3):

after running

```
npm update
```

my problem was solved

Answer (score 2):

yarn is faster than npm. just install yarn. run the following code

```
yarn global add @angular/cli
```

after running this command run, then create your project

```
ng new a4app
```

otherwise uninstall npm and then install latest version

```
npm uninstall --save
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with Angular 6 and the following workaround solved this issue form me,

> npm uninstall @angular/cli -g
>
> npm install @angular/cli -g

Also I switched back to LTS version of node form the latest version to be on safer side.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Problem is resolved on my mac.