# Update Angular to newer version VS 2017

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2017

I am new to node, npm and angular. I picked up this book called 'ASP NET CORE and Angular 5' from packet publishing. I am setting up the environment as specified in the book.

I created a project with default template so it came with angular 4.2.5

I changed the version number from 4.2.5 to 5.0.5 in the `package.json` and rebuilt the solution but I'm still seeing under dependencies/npm 4.2.5 version. The book said to manually update if this doesn't work. I Performed that step as well, under the image, still seeing the same result.

[image]

From inside the root folder, i am trying to run the batch file with the following commands to update. I double clicked on it. The command prompt was showing doing an update...

```
cd %~dp0
npm update
```

[image]

and here is the dependencies/npm folder after the updates. Still showing 4.2.5

[image]

I have followed some other npm update questions already asked but nothing seem to be updating the project for me. How should i update this test project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version), you can do this:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

The `-g` mean global, therefore you will be updating angular system wide and will need admin priviledges.
In a more general way, you can always delete recursively your `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` to get all your packages to the version specified in your `package.json` file.

Comment: Thanks! my mistake... was running npm commands from node command prompt rather than regular one. First step it needs to be `npm cache verify`. I am now updated to latest version (1.7.4) globally.  Then did npm install and the project has 5.0.5 as specified in the config file.

Comment: @learning...  do you run this commands before or after changing the package.json file manually ?

Comment: My package.json file was already changed. In this case it doesn't matter. Once every thing is installed, change package file before issuing 'npm install'.