# updating manually angular version on package json visual studio causes error in node_modules?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I created a new project in Angular, using Visual Studio.
I noticed the angular version that visual studio that was attributed to the project was the 5.2 version of Angular.

My client wants the version to specifically be the version 6 of Angular.
I researched and found out you could just change the version manually on the package.json file. I had an error after doing these changes to the file. I did find some posts here on stackoverflow , which say to run some commands like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869853/update-angular-to-newer-version-vs-2017).

But this hasn't worked out for me. I get this error:

`"ERROR in node_modules/@angular/common/src/location/location.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/ABCUSER/source/repos/ABC/ABC/ClientApp/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'SubscriptionLike'."`

What else should I try?

my **package.json** file can be found here:

`api.myjson.com/bins/e7rcc`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just updating the package.json is specifying which versions you want ... but it does not install them. I don't use Visual Studio, but I assume that there is some way to tell it to reinstall the packages defined in the updated package.json file? In VS Code I would use `npm install` again to install the packages defined in the updated package.json file.

Comment: @DeborahK when you create a project in Angular in Visual Studio (even if you have angular version 7 installed globally on your pc) will always (as of now january 2019) create the project with the version 5.2. But  yes I already tried some commands but I will try to again run install or update comands inside the project folder and see if it can fix that