# ng build --prod does NOT minify / uglify / remove comments since Angular CLI 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, minify, angular-cli-v6

Since I've upgraded my Angular app to use Angular CLI version `6.x`, compiling it for production (using `ng build --prod`, as usual) does not produce minified js. This result in very big `vendor.js` size (in my case is almost 10 MB).

If I open the resulting `vendor.js` file, I can clearly see that the code is not minified and the comments are not removed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue is in `angular.json` file.

Under the key `projects.MY_PROJECT_NAME.architect.build.configurations.production`, I was missing all the options that normally comes by default in the `production` configuration when you create a new angular project.

This is how the `production` configuration should look like in order to fix the issue:

```
"production": {
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  ],
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "extractCss": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": true
},
```

For some reasons, after upgrading from previous Angular CLI versions, my `production` configuration only had the `fileReplacements` key. Adding the other properties shown above (`optimization`, `outputHashing`, etc...) solved the issue for me.