# How to Update Angular Cli

Tags: npm, angular-cli

Just to give you some context.

I was running a project and after ng serve I was getting this warning message:

> **our global Angular CLI version (9.1.4) is greater than your local**
>   version (1.0.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.

I googled and figured out I should update angular cli with the following command.

> **npm install --save -dev @angular/cli@latest**

After that I am getting the following error when trying to build the project:

> **The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found**

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

After reading some issues reported on the GitHub repository, I found the solution.

In order to update the angular-cli package installed globally in your system, you need to run:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Depending on your system, you may need to prefix the above commands with `sudo`.

Also, most likely you want to also update your local project version, because inside your project directory it will be selected with higher priority than the global one:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

After updating your CLI, you probably want to [update your angular version](https://update.angular.io/) too

**Note:** if you are updating to Angular CLI 6+ from an older version, you might need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926816/ng-build-prod-does-not-minify-uglify-remove-comments-since-angular-cli-6/51926817)

**Edit:** In addition, if you were still on a 1.x version of the cli, you need to convert your `angular-cli.json` to `angular.json`, which you can do with the following command:

```
ng update @angular/cli --from=1.7.4 --migrate-only
```

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232874/angular-6-migration-angular-cli-json-to-angular-json) for more details.