# How to remove code comments on `ng build prod`?

Tags: angular

I'm working on Angular 8 and I wish to know if is there a command in order build the application removing the all the comments?

I'm using:

```
ng build prod
```

but it doesn't remove the comments.

Comment: Have you checked [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926816/ng-build-prod-does-not-minify-uglify-remove-comments-since-angular-cli-6/51926817)?

Comment: Yes, but I have not found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if angular.json has correct properties under production
Refer to below sample code

```
"production": {
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  ],
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "extractCss": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": true
},
```