# Can not install latest version of Angular CLI

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I start a new project with Angular, so decided to upgrade my global packages.

I run Windows10. Command `ng -v` returns me:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
```

At the moment of writing this, the latest stable version is 6.2.4, as [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli) says.

In order to upgrade to the latest version I run:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

All commands complete successfully, and now I checking `ng -v` but it is still 6.0.8. I would expect it to be 6.2.4.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you include your path var for better debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `npm upgrade -g @angular/cli` should work properly.

Comment: Wow, it worked. Probably some caching issue occurred. What I was applying is an answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version. It didn't work for me. Thanks @billyjov

Answer (score 0):

You might be running this command from a directory which might have a `node_modules` folder in it.

For example, if you inside of any angular project directory then ng is local not the global one.

Please try running this command from some directory.

Comment: I run it on the empty directory, so it's not the case

Comment: can you try installing `npm install -g @angular/cli@6.2.4`

Comment: If possible can you also post the npm installation log