# upgrade angular 4 project to angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, upgrade, angular-upgrade

I need to upgrade an existing angular 4 project to angular 6

I have followed the steps mentioned in the https://update.angular.io/

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@6
npm install @angular/cli@6
ng update @angular/cli
ng update @angular/core
ng update
```

but these steps are landing in upgrading to angular 7 not angular 6

Screenshot of the result after running the ng update command:
[image: screenshot of the result after running the ng update command]

Am I missing any steps, how to upgrade to angular 6 instead of angular 7

Comment: npm uninstall @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli

Comment: you need specify angular version & cli version to 6 .

Comment: try this : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version and specify the version which you want where @latest is mentioned

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can try giving the full version number that is 6.0.0 where ever you're installing. Secondly, the second install command try adding **--save-dev** flag to it so that it save it to the dev dependencies directly and then **ng update @angular/cli** after that
**ng update** then **ng update @angular/core**. Be sure before the update commands check the ng version using ng --version.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I already tried using the --save-dev flag with the complete version , no luck it is still updating to angular 7

Answer (score 0):

In order to upgrade **angular-cli** package that was installed globally in your system, you need to run following commands

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean or npm cache verify (if npm > 5)
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Instead of upgrading **global version of angular-cli** you can also upgrade the local version for specific project by running following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

hope this will help
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First You need to uninstall both node-modules folder and package-lock.json file.
Next you need to perform a basic update using

> ng update @angular/core

This upgrades your core package.

> ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=YOUR-CURRENT-ANGULAR-VERSION

This upgrades your angular command line tools to support the latest version.

Finally do npm install and run the ng serve command.

Incase you have used rxjs and its throwing errors after upgrading, just npm i rxjs-compat, this will install required dependencies.

Voila,your project is upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by installing nvm, execute below commands in terminal

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | 
bash
```

and next

```
export NVM_DIR="/root/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
nvm uninstall <version>    
nvm install [-s] <version>
nvm alias default <version>
```

or simply change your angular version in package.json and run

```
npm install
```

in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Angular v6

The best resource with details on how to upgrade to a new Angular version is https://update.angular.io/. Even if you are upgrading from v2 to v6, it will list all the breaking changes since v2 to v6! It is a great way to know in details what you need to change in your code.

**1: Instaling latest Angular CLI**

First step is to make sure you have the latest CLI available:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

With the release of Angular v6, the Angular CLI is now also versioned as Angular, meaning until Angular v5, we would use Angular CLI 1.x, and now Angular CLI is also on version 6.x. It makes it much easier!

**2: ng update**

Needless to say, please do create a branch to update your project, as you’ll never know if all dependencies will still work after upgrading to Angular v6.

So first, we will start with `@angular/cli`. In order for the `ng update` command to work inside the project, we need first to update the `@angular/cli` version to 6.x.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Next, run the `ng update` command for `@angular/cli`, then `@angular/core` and then for the other packages required (`rxjs, @angular/material`):

```
ng update @angular/cli
ng update @angular/core
ng update @angular/material
ng update rxjs
```

Some project structure files have changed from v5 to v6. There is no `angular-cli.json` anymore, it has been replaced by `angular.json`. The structure of angular.json also has changed to support multiple projects per workspace. When we run ng update `@angular/cli` all the required files will be updated!

**3: Updating other dependencies**

I also like to update the other npm depedencies used by the project during an Angular upgrade. The npm package npm-check-updates is really helpful for this task.

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Use the command ncu to check what packages have updates available. And `ncu -u` to update your package.json.

When changing versions of package of package.json, I personally also like to delete the node_module and run npm i again just to make sure the correct versions are availavle locally (and also update package-lock.json).

**4: Updating RxJS**

So, next step now is running `ng serve` to check if everything is ok with the code. Don’t forget to verify https://update.angular.io/ for all beaking changes.

Even though we were able to update RxJS code since Angular v5 (with RxJS v5) to use the pipeble operators, in the projects I did the upgrade to v6, I forgot to change a few places. To help us with this task, we can install `rxjs-tslint` to help us removing all deprecated RxJS code.

```
npm install -g rxjs-tslint
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
```

As a quick summary regarding the imports:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of;'
```

**to:**

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
```

Or, if you were not using RxJS pipeble operators yet:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';    
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';   
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';  
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';    
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

**to**

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

The following operators were renamed as well:

```
do -> tap
catch -> catchError
switch -> switchAll
finally -> finalize
```

And in our code, we can start using the pipeble operators.

From:

```
this.http.get('url')
  .do(console.log)
  .map(results => results.data)
  .subscribe(results => {
    console.log('Results', results);
  });
```

**To:**

```
this.http.get('url')
  .pipe(
    tap(console.log), // old 'do' operator
    map(results => results.data)
  )
  .subscribe(results => {
    console.log('Results', results);
  });
```

After updating your RxJS code, you might still get errors regarding RxJS from third-party dependencies. To solve this, install rxjs-compat and once the dependencies have upgraded their code as well, you can remove this package from your project.

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

**5: Simplifying Dependency Injection for Core Services**

A new feature introduced in Angular v6 is called “tree-shakable providers”. This means we no longer need to declare services in a module by using the property `providedIn`, and this will allow the services to be tree-shakable, meaning if they are not being used, they will not be part of the prod bundle.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyCoreService { }
```

I applied this feature in all core services (global scope) of my projects, but I’m still using non tree-shakable providers with services that do not have global scope.

This allowed to clean up the providers section from CoreModule.

**6: Updating Angular Material (optional)**

If you are using Angular Material in your project, don’t forget to run `ng update @angular/material` to update the material dependencies.

A breaking change from v5 to v6 is how we import the Material modules in our project:

From:

```
import {
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdMenuModule,
  MdCardModule
} from '@angular/material';
```

**To:**

```
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
```

Now each module has its own package. This is also one of the reasons I like to create a separate module for thrid party imports as already explained in this article. It makes much easier to fix imports!

Some other things…
I do have some projects that were created since Angular v2, and after every major version update, I usually just updated package.json and fixed the breaking changes in the code and that was ok.

Since there were some project structure changes in Angular CLI v6, I also decided to migrate a project by creating a brand new project with CLI 6 and copying the src folder from the old project to the new project. Below are some of the most impacted changes.

The major difference that had some impact on the code is the baseUrl: './' from tsconfig.json. With projects created with CLI 1.x (for Angular v4 and v5), this configuration is not there by default (but inside src/tsconfig.ap.json). Moving baseUrl to the root tsconfig.json had an impact on custom paths declared in tsconfig.json and also on the path for lazy loading modules.

Before - custom path in `tsconfig.json`:

```
paths: {
  "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
}
```

**After (single project created with CLI v6):**

```
paths: {
  "@env/*": ["src/environments/*"]
}
```

And the lazy loading modules need to be declared using the relative path:

**Before:**

```
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule' }
```

**After:**

```
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' }
```

If you have nested modules, you also need to update them to use relative paths:

**Before (module1-routing.module.ts):**

```
{ path: 'foo', loadChildren: 'app/module1/module2/module2.module#Module2Module' }
```

**After (module1-routing.module.ts):**

```
{ path: 'foo', loadChildren: './module2/module2.module#Module2Module' }
```

There were a few changes in the CLI v6 commands as well.
As the majority of my professional applications use Java in the backend, the output folder (dist) from ng build is configured to a different path. Until CLI 1.x, there was a flag (output-path -op) that could be used in the ng build command (ng build -op ../other/path). With CLI v6, if you need to use a different output path, you need to update angular.json and remove the -op flag from ng build:

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "outputPath": "../other/path",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```