# ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.1.1 and <3.2.0 but 3.2.1 was found instead

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

I am getting this error

> ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.1.1 and <3.2.0 but 3.2.1 was found instead.

Seems like Typescript updated but the Angular Compiler doesn't like that.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Either downgrade typescript or upgrade angular

Comment: Angular 7 fixed this issue. I guess your version of Angular is 6.

Comment: Just realised quite a few people have raised questions similar to this one. Just wanna put a link to my answer over here as I felt that it sufficiently answers it https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216166/10959940

Answer (score 222, accepted):

To fix this install the specific typescript version 3.1.6

```
npm i typescript@3.1.6 --save-dev --save-exact
```

Comment: before that, I had to update my node.js and npm versions on my system to get it work

Comment: Does anyone know what updated the typescript version to 3.2.x in the first place? Is it because that just happens to be the newest version today - and something in my package file that required it is 'unconstrained' so it allowed the update - but Angular's 'allowed' version maxes out at <3.2? Is that why?

Comment: I got myself confused about which angular version supported TS 3.2. The first version is 7.2.0 which is currently in RC0 status, and therefore didn't update to that version by itself.

Comment: This is the solution to update node end ts version. Thanks

Answer (score 163):

In my case below command worked for windows. It will install latest required version between 3.1.1 and 3.2.0. Depending on OS use either double or single quotes

```
npm install typescript@">=3.1.1 <3.2.0"
```

Comment: Just had this happen to me (Angular 7.3.2 but Debian has Typescript 3.3.1 now) and this answer is nicest because I don't need to work out what is the most recent version that meets the criteria Angular provides.

Comment: npm install typescript@">=3.2.0 <3.3.0"

Comment: For Mac worked like npm install typescript@'>=3.1.1  <3.3.0'

Comment: Worked for me :) I used **npm install typescript@">=3.4.0 and <3.5.0" --save-dev --save-exact**

Answer (score 32):

If you want to use Angular with an unsupported TypeScript version, add this to your `tsconfig.json` to ignore the warning:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true,
  },
```

Comment: Thank you. that is very helpful.

Answer (score 27):

First install your targeted version

```
npm i typescript@3.1.6 --save-dev --save-exact
```

Then before compiling do

```
   npm i
```

Answer (score 18):

```
npm install typescript@">=3.1.1 <3.3.0" --save-dev --save-exact
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 9):

> ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.6.3 was found instead.

For this error you can also define a version range:

```
yarn add typescript@">=3.4.0 <3.6.0" --save-dev --save-exact
```

or for npm

```
npm install typescript@">=3.4.0 <3.6.0" --save-dev --save-exact
```

After installing the correct typescript version:

1. Delete `node_modules` folder
2. Run `yarn install` or `npm install`
3. Compile and cross your fingers xD

Answer (score 5):

Got a similar error from CircleCi's error log.

***"ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.1.1 and <3.3.0 but 3.3.3333 was found instead."***

Just so you know this did not affect the Angular application, but the CircleCi error was becoming annoying. I am running Angular 7.1

I ran: 
 $ npm i typescript@3.1.6 --save-dev --save-exact 
to update the package-lock.json file.

Then I ran:
$ npm i

After that I ran:
 $ npm audit fix

"This CircleCi error message" went away.   So it works

Answer (score 1):

For following Error:

> ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0
>   but 3.6.3 was found instead.

Run following NPM command:

```
$ npm install typescript@3.5.3
```

Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-update-local-angular-cli-version/)

Comment: A better approach would be to give him the range: `yarn add typescript@">=3.4.0 <3.6.0" --save-dev --save-exact` or with npm `npm install typescript@">=3.4.0 <3.6.0" --save-dev --save-exact`.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issues when tried to do ng serve. I was able to resolve it as below.
 
**Note:**

```
C:\Windows\system32> is on windows command prompt
C:\apps\workspace\testProj>  is on VS code Terminal (can also be doable in another command prompt)
```

Following are the steps which I used to resolve this.
**Step1**. Verify the cli version installed on command prompt (will be Angular CLI global version)

```
C:\Windows\system32>ng --version
```

Angular CLI: 8.3.13

If cli was installed earlier, it shows the global cli version.

If cli was not installed, we may get the error 
**ng is not recognized as an internal or external command**

**a. (Optional Step)** `Install Angular CLI global version`

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g @angular-cli/latest
```

**b. Check version again**

```
C:\Windows\system32>ng --version
Angular CLI: 8.3.13
```

**Step2. Verify the local cli version installed on your angular project(VS code ide or command prompt cd'd to your project project)**

```
C:\apps\workspace\testProj>ng --version
Angular CLI: 7.3.8
```

**Note: Clearly versions are not in sync. Do the following in your angular project**

```
C:\apps\workspace\testProj>ng update @angular/cli        -> important to sync with global cli version
```

**Note**: If upgrade donot work using above command (ref: [How to upgrade Angular CLI to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version))
On command prompt, `uninstall global angular cli, clean the cache and reinstall the cli`

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm uninstall -g angular-cli
C:\Windows\system32>npm cache clean or npm cache verify #(if npm > 5)
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Now update your local project version, because cli version of your local project is having higher priority than global one when you try to execute your project.

```
C:\apps\workspace\testProj>rm -rf node_modules
C:\apps\workspace\testProj>npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
C:\apps\workspace\testProj>npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
C:\apps\workspace\testProj>npm install
C:\apps\workspace\testProj>ng update @angular/cli
```

**Step3.** Verify if local project cli version now in sync with global one

```
C:\Windows\system32>ng --version
Angular CLI: 8.3.13

C:\apps\workspace\testProj>ng --version
Angular CLI: 8.3.13
```

**Step4.**. Revalidate on the project

```
C:\apps\workspace\testProj>ng serve
```

Should work now