# The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.5.0 but 3.5.3 was found instead

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting the following error when I do npm run build:

> The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.5.0 but 3.5.3
>   was found instead.

I've tried following things separately:

> npm install typescript@">=3.4.0 <3.5.0". Then deleted node_modules and package.json. Run npm install
>
> npm update --force. 
>   Then deleted node_modules and package.json. Run npm install

I'm still getting the error:

My package.json contains following dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-user-idle": "^2.1.2",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "core-js": "^2.6.7",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.5",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.801.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.13",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~12.6.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
```

ng --version gives following output:

```
Angular CLI: 8.1.2
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.1.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.801.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.801.2
@angular-devkit/core              8.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.1.2
@angular/cdk                      8.1.1
@angular/cli                      8.1.2
@angular/http                     7.2.15
@angular/material                 8.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                  8.1.2
@schematics/angular               8.1.2
@schematics/update                0.801.2
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.35.2
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Was getting a similar error when trying to create an app with "ionic start". Uninstalling and reinstalling the node helped me fix it. Might be useful for some.

Answer (score 419, accepted):

### Applicable for Angular 12

For projects that are running on the latest versions of Angular 12, you should be using TypeScript v4.2.x to 4.3.x

```
npm i -D typescript@4.3.5
```

### Applicable for Angular 11

For projects that are running on the latest versions of Angular 11 (11.2.x), it supports up to TypeScript v4.1.5.

```
npm i -D typescript@4.1.5
```

### Applicable for Angular 10 (as of June 2020)

For those who are using Angular 10, please note that TypeScript 3.9 must be installed, as the maintainers have [removed support for TypeScript 3.8](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1000-next8-2020-05-18). The safest bet would be to install the latest version of TypeScript

```
npm i -D typescript@3.9.5
```

### Applicable for Angular 9 (as of May 2020)

For projects that are running on the latest versions of Angular 9 (**v9.1.x**), it supports up to TypeScript v3.8.3. If you are using anything newer than that (such as TypeScript v3.9.0), you should downgrade it and install the supported versions:

```
npm i -D typescript@3.8.3
```

For projects that are running on the earlier versions of Angular 9 (**v9.0.x**), the supported TypeScript versions are TypeScript v3.6.5 to v3.7.5 (inclusive). Installing any other unsupported versions (such as 3.8.3) would result in an error similar to this:

```
ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.8.0 but 3.8.3 was found instead
```

To fix it, you should install the supported versions stated on the error message. I would recommend you to install Typescript 3.7.x,  as this will unlock useful features such as Optional Chaining and Nullish Coalescing.

```
npm i -D typescript@3.7.5
```

Alternatively, you can simply update Angular to the latest minor version (v9.1.x), as this should not contain any breaking changes.

---

### Applicable for Angular 8 (Original Answer)

It seems like you have the latest version (v3.5.3) of TypeScript installed. You should be installing TypeScript v3.4.5 instead, which is the version that is supported by Angular 8.

You can try this command to install the specific version of TypeScript, rather than the latest version.

```
npm i -D typescript@3.4.5
```

In addition, you might want to consider changing the caret `^` for the TypeScript version on your package.json:

- Removing it completely means it will prevent npm from installing/using the most recent minor version (3.5.3).

  "typescript": "3.4.5"
- Changing it to "~" would tell npm that any patch release is acceptable

  "typescript": "~3.4.5" // will use latest version that matches 3.4.X

For more info about the use of the npm packages versioning: https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning

---

### Applicable to those who are working on older Angular versions, such as Angular 2 to 7

```
|-----------------|--------------------|
| Angular version | TypeScript version |
|-----------------|--------------------|
|       6.1.x     |       3.6.x        |
|-----------------|--------------------|
|       7.2.x     |       2.9.x        |
|-----------------|--------------------|
```

Likewise, if we are using any other Angular versions, you may install the respective TypeScript versions.

```
npm i -D typescript@3.6.4
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3) - Refer to the full list of supported TypeScript versions for each Angular Version.

---

### Additional useful information

There is actually a way to install TypeScript versions that are 'not supported' by the Angular version that is installed within your project, as pointed out by [felipesilva](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16071#issuecomment-551614783). One benefit of doing so would be to allow you to install the latests versions of TypeScript (such as `TypeScript 4.1.2` or any of the beta releases) on your project.

On your `tsconfig.json`, you can simply set `disableTypeScriptVersionCheck` as `true`.

```
{
  // ...
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true
  }
}
```

However, do note that doing so is not recommended by the [official Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#disabletypescriptversioncheck):

> Not recommended, as unsupported versions of TypeScript might have
> undefined behavior.

Comment: Do I have to delete the node_modules and do npm install again?

Comment: Hmm.. You can try just the first step, which is to run `npm i --save-dev typescript@3.4.5`, and see if it solves the problem. If it doesn't work, you can try the second method of removing the caret `^`. As suggested by you, I think you can delete node_modules by deleting the entire folder, or by running `rm -r node_modules
`, followed by reinstalling your packages by running `npm i`

Comment: @user123456 what Angular version are you working on?

Comment: Angular 8.2 supports TypeScript 3.5 now, so you can update your answer once again.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15134#issuecomment-516908416

Comment: For anyone looking at the compatibility between NodeJS, Angular and TypeScript, there is this awesome gist: https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

Comment: after running  npm i -D typescript@4.3.5:   npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/compiler-cli@14.2.3
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@14.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"14.2.1" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@14.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!     @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^14.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!

Answer (score 52):

You have two options:

### 1-Automatically:

this will install the right version (**change version numbers based on the error**)

```
npm install typescript@">=3.4.0 and <3.5.0" --save-dev
```

### 2-Manually:

go to `package.json` and change your `typescript` version, If you want to upgrade your angular project to

**Angular 17**  (`npm install typescript@"~5.2.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~5.2.0"
}
```

**Angular 16**  (`npm install typescript@"~4.9.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~4.9.0"
}
```

**Angular 15**  (`npm install typescript@"~4.8.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~4.8.0"
}
```

**Angular 14**  (`npm install typescript@"~4.7.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~4.7.0"
}
```

**Angular 13**  (`npm install typescript@"~4.4.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~4.4.0"
}
```

**Angular 12**  (`npm install typescript@"~4.2.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~4.2.0"
}
```

**Angular 11**  (`npm install typescript@"~4.0.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~4.0.0"
}
```

**Angular 10**  (`npm install typescript@"~3.8.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~3.8.0"
}
```

**Angular 9**  (`npm install typescript@"~3.7.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~3.7.0"
}
```

**Angular 8**    (`npm install typescript@"~3.4.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~3.4.0"
}
```

**Angular 7**   (`npm install typescript@"~3.1.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~3.1.0"
}
```

**Angular 6**   (`npm install typescript@"~2.9.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~2.9.0"
}
```

**Angular 4**   (`npm install typescript@"~2.2.0"  --save-dev`)

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "typescript": "~2.2.0"
}
```

Then run:

```
npm install
```

Comment: In my case, I had to use `npm install typescript@">=3.4.0 and <3.6.0" --save-dev` because the warning was showing the version interval `>=3.4.0 and <3.6.0`.

Comment: This worked for me `npm install typescript@">=4.6.2 and <4.9.0" --save-dev`

Answer (score 23):

Run this script to find exact version

```
npm install typescript@">=3.4.0 and <3.5.0" --save-dev
```

Answer (score 17):

Please uninstall typescript by using the following command:

```
npm uninstall typescript
```

and then install typescript specific version:

```
npm i --save-dev typescript@3.4.5
```

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this problem in my `Angular 9` as well, but with different version numbers.

> ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.8.0
>   but 3.8.2 was found instead.

[image]

What I did was,

1. Went to the [Angular 9 breaking changes](https://angular.io/guide/updating-to-version-9#new-breaking-changes)
2. Searched for `typescript` version and found that it supports only 3.7
3. Edit my `typescript` version in `package.json` as `"typescript": "~3.7.0"`
4. ran `npm i`

The `~` here is important as it will make sure that it will update only to the next patch version (<`3.8.0`), not to the minor versions, if you use `^` it will update to minor versions too(for example, `4.0.0`).

Comment: use this command its work for me

npm i typescript@">=3.6.4 <3.8.0"

Answer (score 5):

Your wrong is "^" `"typescript": "^3.4.0"` in your package.json

the solution is `"typescript": "~3.4.0"`

Answer (score 3):

In my case I received this error when migrating from Angular 10 to Angular 11.

```
An unhandled exception occurred: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.0.0 and <4.2.0 but 4. 2.3 was found instead.
```

To resolve this issue I used this code in Visual Studio where my Angular project exist:

```
npm install typescript@'>==4.0.0 <4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this:

```
npm i --save-dev typescript@~3.4.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Good news!

You can use TypeScript 3.5 if you upgrade to Angular 8.2+. Version 8.1 didn't support it just yet.

Proof: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15134#issuecomment-516908416

Answer (score 2):

If you want to upgrade your angular project to Angular 11

```
npm install typescript@">=4.0.0 and <4.2.0" --save-dev
```

**In package.json :**

```
"devDependencies": {
      ...
      "typescript": "^4.1.5"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is mainly depended on @angular/cli version
so typescript is depend on angular version

when you update angular check this website(devDependency)

https://david-dm.org/angular/angular-cli

and do

npm i --save-dev typescript@3.4.5

3.4.5version is required

Answer (score 1):

use this command its work for me.. Thanks

```
npm i typescript@">=3.6.4 <3.8.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `"typescript": "^3.4.5"` under `devDependencies` in your `package.json` file enter `"typescript": "~3.4.5"` and save the file, then run npm install again. It worked for me.

Comment: Just ran into this with Angular 11 and Typescript 4.0 vs 4.1. "The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.0.0 and <4.1.0 but 4.1.2 was found instead." My package.json had ^4.0.5 which Angular didn't like, but the error message wasn't clear.

Comment: Try ~4.0.5 instead of ^4.0.5. As you used ^ character, it installs the latest version. But if you use ~ character it will install the exact version.

Answer (score 1):

just go into the tsconfig.js file at the end and add disableTypeScriptVersionCheck in a angularCompilerOptions block property as a follow:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true, <-- this prop
  }
}
```

Follow this link for angularCompilerOptions: https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#disabletypescriptversioncheck

Comment: It is worth to mention that as per documentation, this approach is *not recommended, as unsupported versions of TypeScript might have undefined behavior.*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall and again install the typescript so you can install the specific version of typescript as recommended in the error.

```
npm install typescript@ version
```

or you can run

```
npm install typescript@ version --save-dev
```

to save it in the package json

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular 11 use

```
npm i -D typescript@4.0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar error, I run:

```
yarn clean cache
```

If you use npm you can try to run:

```
npm clean cache
```

I'm not sure that is a 100% solution, but I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

All these answers above are good for quickly fixing the immediate problem of the OP, but failed to pinpoint the SemVer violation that this message implies.

In semver philosophy `3.5.3` is a patch upgrade of the `3.5.x` lineage implying no breaking changes. It MUST be compatible with, and MUST be substituable wherever the `3.5.0` is used or required.

So the message - and the underlying checks are bogus to begin with and violate one fundamental rule of semver.

The message should be "*The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=`3.4.0` and <**`3.6.0`** but **`3.6.x`** was found instead*". The underlying checks should only fail if the version found is **`3.6` or superior** and of course version `3.5.3` should be accepted and NOT pose any problem at all.