# Determine Angular's supported TypeScript version

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking for a documentation table somewhere that matches TypeScript versions with Angular versions. Does the information exist?

Comment: Just look at [Angular's `package.json`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/package.json) and rewind to previous release tags.

Comment: Here you go https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

Comment: If you are using Angular 8, this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216110/the-angular-compiler-requires-typescript-3-4-0-and-3-5-0-but-3-5-3-was-found/57216166#57216166 (edited my answer for other applicable versions too)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Angular Web Site](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0) contains details on how to upgrade from one Angular version to another. In the details below, it will explain the minimum supported TypeScript version for each release. It will also mention the required minimum [Node.js](http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/) version.

For example, upgrading from 7 to 8 yields the following:

- Make sure you are using Node.js 10 or later.
- Angular now uses TypeScript 3.4

Note: If you're just looking for every detail, navigate to the source [package.json](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/package.json) file for Angular CLI. In there is a line which specifies the required version of TypeScript. You can navigate among releases by clicking the `Branch` dropdown and selecting `Tags`, where you pick from among the various versions.

Answer (score 6):

You can determine the supported TypeScript version for a given version of Angular CLI directly from the source:

1. Go to [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) on GitHub.
2. Choose the desired release under *Releases*.
3. Click on the tag with the release number in the left-hand summary of the commit details. (This takes you to the source of the chosen release.)
4. Open the file *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)*.
5. You find the supported TypeScript version in the property `typescript` under `devDependencies`.