# Why I get he Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.7.2 was found instead in ng serve?

Tags: angular

Hope evrything is fine ?

I am new to Angular ?

When I try to run ng serve I get the folowing error:

in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.7.2 was found instead.

How ever when I do tsc -v I get Version 3.4.5

Any Reason ?

Comment: Your package.json file references an unsupported TypeScript version.

Comment: @JBNizet I have this  "typescript": "~3.4.5"

Comment: Then execute npm install, and it should install the expected supported version.

Comment: still same issue ?

Comment: Then I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript has probably been installed as dependancy or during a forced upgrade.

As a workaround, and if you know that you don't need the last version of typescript you may want to downgrade typescript.

```
npm install typescript@3.5.3
```

For a better solution, see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216166/3482730