# No matching version found for typescript@3.4.0

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

I'm trying to serve an angular application, but when attempting to downgrade the typescript I get the following error:

> No matching version found for typescript@3.4.0.

If the package isn't present does anyone know how I can get this version typescript installed?

The error when I attempt to serve is the following:

> The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.7.4
>   was found instead

Comment: Try uninstalling typescript `npm uninstall typescript` and install a versioned version `npm i typescript@3.5.3`

Comment: Thanks - that works - If you want to pop that in as the answer I'll mark it as a fix :)

Comment: Its ok if it helped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.5.0 but 3.5.3 was found instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216110/the-angular-compiler-requires-typescript-3-4-0-and-3-5-0-but-3-5-3-was-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found this question here because I had the same problem. The answer already mentioned in the comments and yep it was working.

**Solution**

> npm uninstall typescript
>
> npm install typescript@3.5.3

I was doing a training course and I had to downgrade for the example.

Comment: don't know how adept you are with Docker, but instead of downgrading, why not just run a docker container with the required node version for that course? I am currently upgrading an Ionic 5 / Angular 10 project to 7 / 17, while systemwide running ng 16 / Ionic 6. It's a bit of a drag, but it would be much much more so if I had to install different versions for all the ca. 10 steps on my machine. While being productive with other work that required more current versions. Well, it would be so ineffective to make it impossible, actually.