# ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.8.0 but 3.8.2 was found instead

Tags: angular, angular9

I ran

```
ng version
```

and got the following output:

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.3
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.25
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.25
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.25
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.3
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      9.0.3
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.25
@schematics/angular               9.0.3
@schematics/update                0.900.3
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.8.2
webpack                           4.39.2
```

If I try set the type script lower it complains the project is Angular 9 and can't use that type of type script. Not sure what to do, any help welcomed, thanks.

Comment: What's the purpose for downgrading `typescript`? I highly recommend setting all of your `@angular/XXXX` libraries to the same version (example `9.0.3`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.5.0 but 3.5.3 was found instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216110/the-angular-compiler-requires-typescript-3-4-0-and-3-5-0-but-3-5-3-was-found)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the version which set ng update command: `npm install typescript@3.7.5`

Answer (score 19):

This means that Angular doesn't support TypeScript **3.8.x** yet.

You can bypass this error with `angularCompilerOptions.disableTypeScriptVersionCheck: true` option in

**tsconfig.json**

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
   ...
   "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true,
},
```

See also:

- https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#disabletypescriptversioncheck

Comment: Angular `9.1.0` supposedly does support TypeScript `3.8.x` and yet I still get this warning; [source](https://jaxenter.com/angular-v10-thread-169097.html).

Comment: @xinthose please were you able to resolve this bug? If you did resolve it, how did you go about it, Thanks

Comment: @Paulayo hello; yes, I think I solved it in this post on SO: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60932969/4056146)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I noticed my package-lock.json has typescript : 3.8.3. So I did `npm i typescript@3.7.5` and build my app and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error message saying The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.5.0 but x.x.x was found instead, please perform the following steps:

1. Run `npm i --save-dev-exact typescript@3.4.5`
2. Restart `ng serve` to serve the project on localhost:4200.

Answer (score 0):

Initally Package.json has "typescript": "^3.7.5" and Package-lock.json has 3.9.10 .

I have resolved by giving exact version in Package.json as  "typescript": "3.7.5" and run npm install . package-lock.json typescript property generated with given version.