# ng update never updates @angular/core version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I run the command `ng update`

```
We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

  Name                                  Version                  Command to update
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @angular/core                         9.0.7 -> 9.1.0           ng update @angular/core
```

so I run `ng update @angular/core` and it says `Package '@angular/core' is already up to date.`  How can I resolve this issue?

## `ng v`

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.0
Node: 13.9.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.0
... cli, core, forms, localize
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular       0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer     0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack       0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core                9.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics          9.1.0
@angular/animations                 9.0.7
@angular/common                     9.0.7
@angular/compiler                   9.0.7
@angular/compiler-cli               9.0.7
@angular/language-service           9.0.7
@angular/platform-browser           9.0.7
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   9.0.7
@angular/router                     9.0.7
@ngtools/webpack                    9.0.7
@schematics/angular                 9.1.0
@schematics/update                  0.901.0
rxjs                                6.5.4
typescript                          3.8.3
webpack                             4.41.2
```

I need `@angular/core@9.1.0` so I can use TypeScript `3.8.3` with `ng serve` because I am currently getting errors like these without it: `error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).`.

I have tried deleting and reinstalling `node_modules`, using the `--force` option, specifying the version `@angular/core@9.1.0`, all but to no avail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I followed the steps from this [website](https://medium.com/panya-studio-engineering/angular-cli-update-issues-manually-update-your-angular-project-ba0b1ea1c727), but for `@angular/core`:

```
npm uninstall @angular/core
npm cache verify
npm install @angular/core@latest
```

`ng update` now shows `We analyzed your package.json and everything seems to be in order. Good work!`

`npm ls @angular/core` showed me this:

```
C:\Users\jsmith\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@9.1.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@9.0.7, required by @angular/forms@9.0.7
```

So I replace all of `9.0.7` in `package.json` with `9.1.0`, then `npm i` and my issues are resolved!

When you update `@angular/core`, it seems that all other `@angular` packages need to have the same version, regardless of `^` being used or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the force flag

```
ng update @angular/core@9.1.0 --force
```