# Docker - ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.9.0 but 3.9.7 was found instead

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I am Dockerizing Angular 9.  When I run in development with `ng serve` it all works perfectly.

Also when I run the docker container on my locoed development environment (macOS), it works fine.

When I try build Angular in a docker container on a centos linux server, I get the following error:

> ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.9.0
> but 3.9.7 was found instead.

**Question**

Anyone know how I can make the compile in docker use the right typescript version?

It's as if in docker, the compiler ignores the typscript version in the package.json.

More info:

**package.json**

```
"typescript": "^3.8.3"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# stage 1
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --output-path=/dist

# stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=0 /dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Should I be using a specific version of node here?  `FROM node`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.5.0 but 3.5.3 was found instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216110/the-angular-compiler-requires-typescript-3-4-0-and-3-5-0-but-3-5-3-was-found)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the Dockerfile solved the issue:

```
RUN npm i -D typescript@3.8.3
```