# TypeScript version not compatible with Angular 11 after generating client code

Tags: typescript, openapi, openapi-generator, springdoc

I am not able to compile the generated client because the TypeScript version is not compatible with Angular 11:

```
ERROR: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.0.0 and <4.1.0 but 3.5.3 was found instead.
```

How can I set the correct TypeScript version while I generate the code? This is how I defined the gradle task:

```kotlin
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = 'typescript-angular'
    inputSpec = swaggerFilePath
    outputDir = apiClientOutputDir
    configOptions = [
            npmName   : 'rest-client',
            npmVersion: '0.0.0',
            ngVersion: '11.0.6'
    ]
}
```

This is what gets written into the `package.json`-file of the `rest-client` module.

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.6",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.35.0",
    "typescript": ">=3.4.0 <3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  }
```

My dependencies:

```kotlin
// Spring Docs
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.2'
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-data-rest:1.5.2'
```

Comment: `npm i -D typescript@^4.0.0`

Comment: Could you please check all your dependencies, they seem to be outdated at all and angular uses different higher versions. Do you may should check these by ```npm outdated``` So you could check if something should be updated.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I'm not sure but I think Angular 11 requires `typescript >=3.4.0 <3.6.0`. Using >=4.0.0 did not work.

Comment: the error message says `TypeScript >=4.0.0 and <4.1.0`. So, a version of `4.0.x` should solve that error message.

Comment: Actually, for Angular 11, you need to use TS 4 and above https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216166/10959940

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using an outdated version of the OpenAPI Generator that didn't know about Angular 11.

Changing

```kotlin
id 'org.openapi.generator' version '4.2.2'
```

to

```kotlin
id 'org.openapi.generator' version '5.0.0'
```

resolved the issue.

I also upgraded my Spring Doc dependencies to the latest version at this time:

```kotlin
// Spring Docs
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.2'
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-data-rest:1.5.2'
```