# ERROR WHILE RUNNING ionic serve: [ng] Error: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.4.2 and <4.5.0 but 4.5.2 was found instead

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm

I was trying to run the ionic serve command but I keep getting the error

```
[ng] Error: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.4.2 and <4.5.0 but 4.5.2 was found instead.
```

When I tried downgrading the typescript using this command

```
npm install typescript@">=4.4.2 <4.5.0" --save-dev --save-exact
```

And Also running the `npm i` ;
The `ionic serve` command gets stuck at the generating browser application bundle phase setup.

When I checked my angular version I got the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j5xh.png)

```
Angular CLI: 13.0.4
Node: 16.10.0
Package Manager: npm 8.1.4
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.0.3
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1300.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.0.4
@angular-devkit/core            13.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.0.4
@angular/cli                    13.0.4
@schematics/angular             13.0.4
rxjs                            6.5.5
typescript                      4.5.2
```

**Please, I need some help:**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216166/14748677) helped me. But it refers to a maximum of version 12 Angular. For version 13 Angular, I used this in the project:

> `npm i -D typescript@4.4`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- replace `typescript 4.5.2` with `typescript 4.4.4`
- save packages.json
- run `npm i` again

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have tried to replace it with 'typescript 4.4.4' and also run 'npm i'. But when I run the 'ionic serve' it gets stuck at the 'generating browser application bundle phase setup' stage and does not go beyond that stage

Comment: Can you also try to remove package-lock.json?

Comment: Also, has ionic serve worked before this în your app? This might also be caused by webpack choking on invalid css for exemple, so tracing your steps back to your latest working version should work as well.