# Elastic Apm Rum Angular's implementation showing Error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement the `@elastic/apm-rum-angular@2.1.1` package, but I'm getting a few console warnings from Angular regarding this package.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@elastic/apm-rum-angular/apm.service.d.ts:28:13 - error TS1005: '=' expected. 
28 import type import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core'; 
node_modules/@elastic/apm-rum-angular/apm.service.d.ts:29:29 - error TS1005: ';' 
expected 29 { AgentConfigOptions } from '@elastic/apm-rum';
```

My ecosystem:

```
angular v 9.0.6,
typescript v 3.6.4
node v 16.13.0
npm v 8.1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to issue ticket [Angular implementation showing Error
#1115](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-rum-js/issues/1115), the issue is caused by `@elastic/apm-rum-angular` version 2.x using type-only imports, which are only supported [starting at TypeScript 3.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export). A pull request was merged that closed that issue ticket: [fix(rum-angular): recover compatibility with angular 9.0.x #1124](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-rum-js/pull/1124). You can also upgrade `@angular/core` to version 9.1, since that one uses TypeScript 3.8 as a dependency (see also [The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.5.0 but 3.5.3 was found instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57216110/11107541)).