# can't find compiler ngcc module after upgrading Angular and project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I've just upgraded Angular cli and one of my project from 7.0.7 to 7.1.0.

I've followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version) and [@Francesco Borzi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3497671/francesco-borzi) answer.

now I've tried running my project using:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

and got this message

> Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc' Error: Cannot find
>
> module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc'
>
> ```
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15)
>
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:575:25)
>
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
>
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
>
> at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/path/myproject/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:10:16)
>
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
>
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
>
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
>
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
>
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
>
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
>
> at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/path/myproject/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:23:26)
>
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
>
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
> ```

here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "angular": "^1.7.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "1.9.1",
    "ngx-gallery": "^5.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^2.0.0-next.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your package.json file, change the @angular/cli version in devDependencies to:

```
"@angular/cli": "7.1.0"
```

There is a version mismatch between your project and the devDependency. You might have probably used `npm audit fix --force` or a similar auto update command, which might have updated the devDependencies in "package.json" file.

You can also use angular cli version 7.3.5 in devDependencies here. Just make sure that the development version and the version mentioned in devDependencies are compatible. Be aware that local anglular/cli version doesn't really matter here.

Update: After making the change, delete "package-lock.json" and delete the "node modules" folder. Run `npm install` to install the modules again.

Comment: same problem here. Should I install/update angular-cli 7.1.0 first before serving?

Comment: You shouldn't necessarily have to do that. But give it a try. But definitely try this: remove 'package-lock.json' and delete 'node modules'. Run 'npm install' to install the modules again.

Comment: Is no angular/cli in package.json

Answer (score 11):

I got same error and solved this by updating @angular/cli global.
like:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

then tried creating new app and copied some dependencies from package.json file to current project because npm install doesn't install latest version of packages. then

```
npm install
```

this solved my problem but then I found this answer: [update angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470993/ng-upgrade-command-fails-for-upgrading-cli-from-v7-to-v8)

Comment: is there any relation of dependencies bewteen devkit-cli-compiler-cli and language service of angular?

Comment: today I upgraded to angular 9, but I cannot find ngcc anywhere

Comment: npm update and npm audit fix should resolve the issue.

Comment: You could of done this simply by doing `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`, there should be no need to run `uninstall`

Comment: Nope still same error

Answer (score 6):

All of that doesn't work for me, I was trying to upgrade from Angular 7 to Angular 8 and here is the working solution for me:

1. npm outdated.
2. npm update.
3. npm install -g npm-check.
4. npm-check -u --skip-unused.
5. Upgrade all the outdated packages except the sass ones using npm-check.
6. npm update.
7. If you have ViewChild on your application, be sure to edit them to `@ViewChild(<name>, {static: true})`.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will resolve your installation related issues

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

Just try the below :
`1- ng serve` isn't working or  ngcc failed just enter :

```
the project folder -- app folder -- node_modules -- @angular -- compiler-cli -- ngcc
```

and delete ngcc lock file. Then ng serve and it will work.

Comment: What if I cannot find the ngcc lock file?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled `@angular/cli` but still was met with an error on `npm i`.

So I used `npm ci` (short for clean install) instead, *and still received the error at hand.*

Things seemed really weird, so I resorted to the strategy which seems to fix most inexplicable behaviors: I opened a new terminal window. This time, `npm ci; ng serve` ran.

I wish I had an explanation for what is going on, but I really don't. My best guess is some bad data was cached and a new lookup needed to run. In any case, please don't put down the answer for lack of elaboration, I'm posting for the sake of those who are desperately trying to get on with their work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was to change the folder names referenced in the scripts to not use any characters like "&".

I also tried running through powershell vs cmd and made sure when executing any commands that one process was running at a time to reduce locks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are having an error like this

> -cli\ngcc\src\analysis\decoration_analyzer.js:159
> finally { if (e_1) throw e_1.error; }
> ^

What worked for me was delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and the running `npm install` again.

After that project run as expected.