# ng upgrade command fails for upgrading cli from v7 to v8

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-upgrade, angular-cli-v7

The ng upgrade command for updating cli version from a v7 project to v8 fails.

Manually trying to upgrade cli first also fails.

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

> Your global Angular CLI version (8.0.1) is greater than your local
>   version (7.3.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

Package `"@angular/compiler-cli"` has an incompatible peer dependency to "`typescript`" `(requires ">=3.1.1 <3.3", would install "3.4.5")`.
Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try upgrading all packages using `ng update --all --force` if this doesn't work then try upgrading core and CLI `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli`.

and still not working then install typescript manually using `npm i typescript@3.4`

Comment: Your solution is should solve the OP's issues, though I would disagree on installing the latest version of typescript, as the Angular CLI/transpiler/compiler only supports up to a specific TypeScript version

Comment: totally agree with you @wentjun, updated the answer and thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Unknown argument all

Answer (score 1):

Like answer above, force the update, but in my case typescript@latest doesn't work because angular requires typescipt@3.4. If you force all it install 3.5 version and you must downgraded it