# ng update --all says 'Repository is not clean' even though git commit

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to update my Angular with `ng update --all` as in this question stated [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419456/cant-find-compiler-ngcc-module-after-upgrading-angular-and-project], but it always says `Repository is not clean.  Please commit or stash any changes before updating.`

I have run the following commands today:

```
npm install
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install --save font-awesome angular-font-awesome
npm install angular-alert-module --save
```

At this state the program compiled

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

since then it does not compile

I read I need to do `ng update --all --force` but it doesn't work because the repository 'is not clean'.

I made a commit pushed it and pulled (where there were no changes) before. But it didn't help

```
ng update --all --force
```

The error-message is:

```
Repository is not clean.  Please commit or stash any changes before updating.
```

Comment: What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: On branch detail-search
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/detail-search'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   package-lock.json

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: And sorry, I forgot to include: When I try to compile it comes: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc'
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
...

Comment: you need to `git add --all` and then `commit`. You have modified package-lock.json.

Comment: Open a new question for your compile error, trying to pinpoint the faulty part.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I write the issue in the answer

Answer (score 8):

You should use `--allow-dirty` if you want to bypass that warning.

This works on @angular/cli v8.0.1+.

```
ng update --all --allow-dirty
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue was, that I commited all files (including the package-lock.json) it did mark it as modified. (I don't know why). Therefore the tree was not possible.

Because commiting was not possible (even though the error message suggests it), I had to stash it. Then it worked, but I had to stash after every command.