# how upgrade angular cli 6 to angular cli 8

Tags: angular-cli

i have the version 6.2.3 of angular cli, and for the node js i have the vesion 12.6.0

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.3
Node: 12.6.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    <error>
@angular-devkit/core         <error>
@angular-devkit/schematics   <error>
@schematics/angular          <error>
@schematics/update           <error>
rxjs                         <error>
```

i want to upgrade to angular 8, i followed the below command, but it stayed the some version

> npm uninstall -g angular-cli
>
> npm cache verify
>
> npm cache clean
>
> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade Angular CLI to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: To update the versions of Angular you're using, check out the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io) for more info.