# Why is ng build failing on azureDevOps?

Tags: angular, azure-devops

I am trying to do CI/CD with Azure devops and the below task is failing.

Here is the package.json file info:

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build --prod",
```

Here is the error message:

[image: Error message]
[image]

I have tried removing --prod, creating a custom build argument, and editing the Yaml to manually call ng build

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the angular cli... maybe try `npm run build` and see if that works?

Comment: The message says it can’t find the angular-devkit/build-angular module in line 32. Is that pointing to the correct location? It seems like that might cause an issue with the build process.

Comment: is says in the error log that your missing 'node_modules', which means you needs to run `npm install` before the build step

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your environment the following npm and node versions are set:

```
npm 6.9.0
node 10.16.3
```

There is an issue, that npm doesn't support this node.js version: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2134.

To fix that you need to add 'Node.js tool installer' task to settle node.js version to supported 8.11.2 (or check which version you use) one, before npm install task in your pipeline: 
[image]

Comment: Please updated your question with pipeline steps. It should be like: 1. Install Node. 2 npm install. 3. npm install -g @angular/cli 4. ng build --prod (this step gives you dist folder) 5. Copy dist folder to artifactstagingdirectory 6. Publish Artifact

Comment: Also what npm, node and angular versions you use?

Comment: Check [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) site to help you with versions

Comment: Failing for me even after following above steps

Answer (score 1):

> Why is ng build failing on azureDevOps?

There is known issue about this issue on the github:

[Module build failed error when run ' ng build prod'](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9842)

And this issue was originally reported a long time ago and since then we've had many releases, one of which might have addressed this problem. Please update to the most recent Angular CLI version.

So, please try to update the Angular CLI version on the agent:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean or npm cache verify #(if npm > 5)
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version) for some more details.

Hope this helps.