# How do I execute the 'ng build' command in Azure DevOps?

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-devops

In Azure DevOps I'm using the 'npm task' to install a package.
The next action is to use a Command Line task to run the 'ng build' command. However, I get an error message that ng command does not exist.

How do I execute the 'ng build' command using tasks in Azure DevOps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512504/why-is-ng-build-failing-on-azuredevops

Comment: Is the ng build not necessary since it's already part of the package.json? (which is ran using npm install?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a prior task, make sure that the following npm and node versions are set

[image]

Add **`'Node.js tool installer'`** task to settle node.js version to supported

Comment: If I add the Command Line after the Node JS Tool Installer it's still missing the NG. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: If the package.json already has the 'ng build' command, is it still necessary to execute this 'ng build' command?

Comment: Post your pipeline log please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your *package.json* file includes *@angular/cli*, the `ng` command should be located in your *node_modules* folder, usually under *node_modules/.bin/ng.cmd*. You can use the `node_modules/.bin/ng.cmd build` command to build.

However, people don't usually do this, as there are two better options. You can add a *scripts* section in your *package.json* file, say

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
  },
```

allowing you to use the npm to run these commands with `npm run build`.

Another option that you will see online is to install *@angular/cli* globally with `npm install -g @angular/cli`, allowing you to use the `ng` command anywhere. However, for specifying version per project, a global installation is not ideal.