# How to downgrade angular version? Not CLI version

Tags: angular

This is my angular version 8.2.14 and my angular CLI version is 6.2.9.

I need to downgrade the angular version to 6.1.9 or something to 6

Because I'm getting this error when I run ng serve

[image]
[image: Right now this is the version]

Right now this is the version

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade ?

Comment: I'm getting the above error?can you help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Did you try to delete the `node_modules` and to install again ?
What I am seeing here it is the `app-shell` which you are having error can you explain what is that ?

Comment: I'm that error when I run ng serve. I have deleted the node modules and tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simpler and better to update angular CLI.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean or npm cache verify #(if npm > 5)
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

[More info how to update angular CLI to newest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version)

But if you want install older version of angular you should change all angular packages in `package.js` and then remove `node_modules` directory and run `npm install` or `yarn install` (if you are using yarn).

I don't know what package you are using but it should look like this (change all packages with `@angular` on name):

```
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
```

Answer (score -2):

No need to stress

The answer is very simple go into your package.json file and change the version number to your desired version number.

Viola and run npm install.

Done.