# Unable to get Angular CLI version, though all the requirements are installed?

Tags: node.js, angular, macos, npm, angular-cli

I am having difficulties doing anything with the Angular CLI. I have Node, NPM. and Angular all installed, when I run the `which` command in the terminal they all exist in my `/user/local/bin`

This is my current `node.js`: v11.8.0

This is my current `npm`: 6.5.0

When I run `ng -v` I am unable to get the version and I get the following message:

```
$ ng -v
Node.js version v11.8.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v10.13 or v12.0.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

I have tried uninstalling the Angular CLI but, getting the same results.

Comment: try ```ng --version```

Comment: Or just reboot your system once and try again.

Comment: I still get the same message from my post.

Comment: Got the same result even after a reboot.

Comment: the command should be >ng version

Comment: If I do ng version, I still get the same result. I am unable to complete any ng commands since I still keep getting the same error about my Node.js version.

Comment: I would unistall and install. See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version

Comment: @rickz I've have tried uninstalling and re-installing following that SO post, and still got the same results...

Comment: According to  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli   you have proper  Prerequisites. But, maybe something is wrong with your node or npm?

Comment: @rickz I find it very weird too, I followed the Prerequisites and I have installed node with Homebrew. I am using the same Node and NPM set up for another project that uses Nuxt.js and I'm not running into any issues there... And I rather not completely uninstall node and npm to interfere with that other project.

Comment: One  more thing, did you see what Mattijs posted in response to my comment under accepted  answer  at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version that helped me. But today use 9.0.2

Comment: @rickz Ok, after I uninstalled it and gave it a specific version to. install now it was able to work. I guess my system can only run angular 7 since any version after that causes me to get the same issue.

Comment: @Tanner how did you install node on your system?

Comment: @kuncevic.dev I installed Nodejs with homebrew

Comment: @Tanner just updated the answer how to uninstall nodejs if being installed that with a brew

Answer (score 9):

Angular CLI requires a current, active LTS, or maintenance LTS version of Node (https://angular.io/guide/setup-local#nodejs). which version 11 isn't.

Node.JS 11 is no longer supported by the Node.Js team as after six months, odd-numbered releases (9, 11, etc.) become unsupported. More info: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases

Solution : Upgrade Node version to 12+

Comment: Ah that make sense, thank you for the clarification information!

Answer (score 7):

As, the Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v10.13 or v12.0.

STEP 1: Install v12.x

```
nvm install 12
```

STEP 2: Use v12.x

```
nvm use 12
```

STEP 3: Install Angular CLI

```
npm install @angular/cli -g
```

STEP 4: Check version, verify its installed

```
ng --version
```

sample image of output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jr15.png

Answer (score 7):

For node v8 install version of angular cli 7.3

```
npm i @angular/cli@7.3.10
```

Comment: works for node v10 too.

Answer (score 4):

Searched for any references of unwanted versions and found it in node_modules in user folder.

```
rm -rf ~/node_modules
```

Checked with:

```
npx node -v
```

and it gave me desired version.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem, did below steps, and was able to resolve

```
nvm install 12
nvm use 12
npm install @angular/cli -g
ng --version
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to simply go to the node.js [download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) website, get the current/latest version of the software and install it on my computer. After that, the `ng new` command worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It’s your Angular CLI version installed

The Angular, Angular CLI & Node have version compatibility matrix
https://angular.io/guide/versions

NOTE: Mostly, Your Angular CLI version (> 6.0.x) will corresponds to the version of Angular that will be installed through `$ ng new` command

For example if you have @angular/cli version 15.x.x, then your skeleton application angular version will have version similar to 15.x.x

---

Solution is,
Decide the angular version you want to work with. Then install coresponding node & angular cli

You can uninstall the current angular cli installed
& then install a specific version of angular cli
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli?activeTab=versions

For example:

```
$ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
$ npm install -g @angular/cli@x.x.x
```