# Can't install correct Angular/CLI version

Tags: node.js, angular, macos, npm

I'm trying to install nodejs version 10.x on macos, along with angular cli. But each time I try, I get errors about ng not being compatible with the version of node.

I've been following the post here
[Unable to get Angular CLI version, though all the requirements are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200991/unable-to-get-angular-cli-version-though-all-the-requirements-are-installed)

I don't get any errors during install but i keep getting the error:

```
adminMini:client admin$ ng -v
Node.js version v10.24.1 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v12.14 or v14.15.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

This is how I installed angular:

```
adminMini:client admin$ nvm use 10
Now using node v10.24.1 (npm v6.14.12)

adminMini:client admin$ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
removed 235 packages in 2.001s

adminMini:client admin$ nvm use 10
Now using node v10.24.1 (npm v6.14.12)
adminMini:client admin$ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
/Users/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/bin/ng -> /Users/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@12.1.0 postinstall /Users/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @angular/cli@12.1.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0","npm":"^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.1","npm":"6.14.12"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @angular/cli@12.1.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @angular-devkit/architect@0.1201.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0","npm":"^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.1","npm":"6.14.12"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @angular-devkit/architect@0.1201.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @angular-devkit/core@12.1.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0","npm":"^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.1","npm":"6.14.12"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @angular-devkit/core@12.1.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @angular-devkit/schematics@12.1.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0","npm":"^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.1","npm":"6.14.12"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @angular-devkit/schematics@12.1.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @schematics/angular@12.1.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0","npm":"^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6","yarn":">= 1.13.0"} (current: {"node":"10.24.1","npm":"6.14.12"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @schematics/angular@12.1.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for open@8.2.1: wanted: {"node":">=12"} (current: {"node":"10.24.1","npm":"6.14.12"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: open@8.2.1

+ @angular/cli@12.1.0
added 235 packages from 180 contributors in 7.702s
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Node.js 10.x is unsupported. Like, not just unsupported by Angular, but unsupported by the Node.js project. Update to 12.x, 14.x, or 16.x (which are the supported versions as of this writing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the command `npm install -g @angular/cli` you will install the latest version of angular and it requires the version 12 of node.

So you will need to update your node version to 12 or install a previous version of angular by indicating the verison to the install script

```
npm -g install @angular/cli@8.3.25
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already using `nvm`, try installing node latest version using nvm like this:

```
nvm install --lts
```

Check the latest nvm version which should greater than `12`. The reason is angular version 8 dependencies don't run well with lower version of node. And it is also recommended to keep the version updated for security vulnerability.

This will list the version, select the version `v12.14 or v14.15` or `LTS`

```
nvm list
.....
nvm use v12.14
```

After this install the angular version 8+ using this [link](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local).