# How to change the angular version to fix compatibility issue with CLI

Tags: angular

I'm using below versions for running an angular app:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.14
Node: 14.15.5
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 12.1.0
```

But while trying to run the project with `npm start`, I'm getting below error:

> This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^8.0.0-beta || >=8.0.0 <9.0.0,
> but Angular version 12.1.0 was found instead.

Can someone help me to change its version to fix this issue and run the solution.

Comment: You need to upgrade your global CLI version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version

Comment: Why _are_ you using Angular CLI 8 with Angular 12? Normally the upgrade path is `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

After updating it is better to clean cache form npm too:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and install project packages again:

```
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```