# Unable to run ionic cordova run android -l

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I’m using ionic 6.20.6 and angular 15.0.4 with latest gradle and android studio, also I have cordova 11 installed but when running ionic cordova run android -l I’m getting the following error:

```
ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-serve --host=localhost --port=8100 --platform=android
[ng] This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^14.0.0,
[ng] but Angular version 15.0.4 was found instead.
[ng]
[ng] Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
[ng] https://update.angular.io/
[ng]
[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 3).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

The ionic documentation says that ionic 6 supports angular 15+ but I'm not able to run it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade Angular CLI to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931986/how-to-upgrade-angular-cli-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: As the message states, you need to update you CLI.

Comment: I'm already on the latest version of @angular/cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out `@ionic/cordova-builders` does not support @angular v15 yet.
The only to use cordova in Ionic Angular project is to use angular v14 for now and wait for `@ionic/cordova-builders` to support angular v15